# How to set Auth0 configuration for angular app?

Tags: angular, auth0, auth0-lock

I'm trying to use **Auth0** in **angular app**, but when I set the configuration in [https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/]
I got this error when click on **save changes button**

> Error!Payload validation error: 'Object didn't pass validation for
> format absolute-https-uri-or-empty: https://localhost:4200/en/signin'
> on property initiate_login_uri (Initiate login uri, must be https).

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 6):

change your **Application Login URI**  `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

so your URI will look like that `https://127.0.0.1:4200/en/signin`

source: [Application Login URI field](https://community.auth0.com/t/application-login-uri-field-payload-validation-error-for-https-localhost-3000-authorize/31554/20)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Login URI to `//https://127.0.0.1:4200`

Note: it requires `https://` not `http://`

[**source**](https://community.auth0.com/t/application-login-uri-field-payload-validation-error-for-https-localhost-5001-authorize/66928)